# passing more then one path to xPath query

Tags: php

I have links with a different paths, and trying retrieve data from those links. So I don't want to do it separate. Made a query list, and used foreach on that list.

```
function passPath($list){
    $list = [
        "//li[@class='out']/a[1]",
        "//ul[@class='ul right_ul clearfix']/li[2]/a",
        "//ul[@class='ul right_ul clearfix']/li[2]/a"
    ];
    foreach($list as $val){
        return $val;
    }
}
```

Then used that function inside DOMXpath's query.

```
function getPath($urls){
    foreach($urls as $k => $val){
            $url = $urls;
            $html = content($val);
            $path = new \DOMXPath($html);
            $xPath = passPath($val);
            $route = $path->query($xPath);
            foreach($route as $value){
                if ($value->nodeValue != false) {
                    $urls [] = trim($value->getAttribute('href'));
                    unset($urls[$k]);
                }
            }
    }
    return array_unique($urls);
}
```

it's running without an error. But there is foreach problem here. because it's just retrieving one element's data. not keep going other elements... What I am missing here?

```
$data = getPath($urls)
var_dump($data)
```

by the way: `content()` is `file_get_content/loadHTML` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code for earning list of `href`.

```php
# You want to parse all pages using url list. So you created function named `getPath($urls)`.
function getPath($urls) {
    # I suggest you'd rather declare $ret for storing values to return.
    $ret = [];

    # Using foreach, you can parse all url.
    foreach ($urls as $k => $url) { # $val is url value of $urls. And I changed $val to $url.

        # content() is file_get_content/loadHTML function.
        $html = content($url);

        # Create new DOMXPath object using $html.
        $path = new \DOMXPath($html);

        # This function is not required.
        # By the way, second element and third element of $xPathList are equal. I think the third element is not required.
        // $xPath = passPath($url);
        $xPathList = [
            "//li[@class='out']/a[1]",
            "//ul[@class='ul right_ul clearfix']/li[2]/a",
            "//ul[@class='ul right_ul clearfix']/li[2]/a"
        ];

        foreach ($xPathList as $xPath) {
            $nodes = $path->query($xPath);
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                if ($node->nodeValue != false) {
                    $ret[] = trim($node->getAttribute('href'));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return array_unique($ret);
}

$data = getPath($urls);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: it's working fine perfectly. thanks a lot. By the way if you have time could you please check this question out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114980/cant-parse-data-with-xpath

Comment: I saw your anathor question, but I cannot find what is the cause because of your information was not enough. I want information about `$html = cache()->rememberForever()` function and what error was occured.